# Как узнать количество доступных потоков?

Tags: linux, c++, pthread

Собственно, заголовок вопроса практически описывает весь вопрос.

Добавлю только то, что пишу я учебную программу на С++ под линукс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я знаю один способ - создавать их в цикле до тех пор, пока оно создается. Под 32-разрядными системами обычно их получается сильно меньше. Вот есть готовые [сорцы](http://people.redhat.com/alikins/tuning_utils/thread-limit.c).

У меня выводит  485 потоков (16 гиг оперативы, i7 процессор).

Но если сделать

```
ulimit -u 4096
ulimit -s 512
```

то количество тредов сразу подымается до 3557.

**Обновление**

Можно только сделать оценку, но точное количество не посчитать - слишком много факторов.

В целом, для каждого приложения в 32-битной системе доступно 4Гб памяти. Но по факту - 2 (или 3)Гб. Так как каждый поток при создании получает мегабайтный стек, то больше 2000-3000 потоков создать невозможно. На практике это около 300-400, так как нужны накладные расходы на создание потоков.

Я задал параметр `-u`, который как раз и определяет максимальное количество  процессов в системе. Вычитая с него текущее количество процессов в системе, можно оценить максимальное - количество создаваемых потоков.

Comment: А если необходимо знать, сколько потоков создавать *до* того, как начинать их создавать?

Comment: Обновил ответ.